# Remove duplication of combination 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I want to remove all duplicates where combination of first name and last name is same

table users
mysql> select * from users;

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | LastName   | FirstName |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | Kowalski   | Jan       |
|  2 | Malinowski | Marian    |
|  3 | Malinowski | Marian    |
|  4 | Kowalski   | Jan       |
|  5 | Malinowski | Marian    |
|  6 | Malinowski | Marian    |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

I've created script

```
set @x = 1;
set @previous_name = '';


DELETE FROM users where id IN (SELECT id from (
    select id, @previous_name,IF (CONCAT(FirstName, LastName) = @previous_name, @x:= @x + 1, IF(@previous_name:=CONCAT(FirstName, LastName), @x, IF(@x:=1, @x, @x))) as occurance
        from users order by CONCAT(FirstName, LastName)
    ) AS occurance_table where occurance_table.occurance > 1);
```

but sql returns error

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'JanKowalski'
```

I found a few similar questions, but solution were remove `and` word form syntax.

I want to prepare db for adding unique constrain for 2 columns, so I want to clear table from duplications.

What is best way to reach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with the query mentioned in Answer section.
I believe that does not work. Instead I have modified the query to work

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN
(
  SELECT MIN(a.id)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM users) a
  GROUP BY a.LastName, a.FirstName
  )
```

Please do correct me if I am wrong. @juergen

Comment: That is right. You need a temp table to not update the same table you select from. I also changed the query.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a script. A single query is enough:

```
delete u1
from users u1
left join 
(
  select min(id) as min_id
  from users
  group by LastName, FirstName
) u2 on u1.id = u2.min_id
where u2.min_id is null
```

The subselect gets the lowest user id for each unique set of name. Joining to that you can delete everything else.